# What is the most efficient way to read in a list of numbers separated by spaces in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, input

Recently, I've been trying some competition coding and a very common thing (at least common from my viewpoint) is to provide a list of integers separated by spaces as an input.  For example:

```
>>> 5 6 7 8 8 1 3 2
```

I want to be able to read this input in and turn it into a list in Python:

```py
>>> 5 6 7 8 8 1 3 2
[5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 1, 3, 2]
```

So far, this is the most efficient method I've encountered:

```py
newList = list(map(int, input.split()))
print(newList)
```

I've also seen a method where you read in the input as a string, then make it a list, but I think `map` is still more efficient.
Is there any way more efficient than this to read in a list of integers and turn it into a list?  Thanks!

Comment: "I've also seen the .split() method, but I think map is still more efficient." - You are using both in your current method.

Comment: This comes down to semantics, preference, and what some may call *Pythonic*.  Based on the given sample inputs, what you have is fine. You are probably saving a few cycles compared to enumerating `input.split()` and appending to a list, but the performance increase is negligible. The solution is effectively `O(n)` either way.

Comment: @h0r53 yeah I fixed that, that was probably a bit unclear, sorry.  I didn't realize that map was `O(n)`, cool!

Comment: `map` just calls a function for each element in a collection. So the function is called `n` times where `n` is the number of items in the collection. `map` itself isn't necessarily `O(n)`, but calling `map()` `n` times is. `int()` is `O(1)`. So you have `O(n) * O(1)` = `O(n)` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
print("5 6 7 8 8 1 3 2".replace(" ",","))
print("5,6,7,8,8,1,3,2".replace(","," "))
```

Answer (score 1):

this is what you looking for i think

```
print(" ".join([5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 1, 3, 2])) # for converting to  "[5 6 7 8 8 1 3 2"
print("5 6 7 8 8 1 3 2".split(" ")) #for converting back
```

Comment: That's actually not quite what I'm looking for, although it certainly is a good method for joining/splitting strings into lists.

Comment: tell me what you expect in input and output i will write  you code now

Comment: Input: Space separated list of integers; Output: The same list of integers, but it's now a python list separated by commas and not spaces